# Need help about Apple Push Notification

Tags: ios, notifications, push

May I get the exact date and time when the push was received by the device (inside the "didReceiveRemoteNotification" function) after I tap on it. Actually I need to run a timer of 30 secs from the time when Push is received by the device. Please help me out of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can take the current date time in didReceiveRemoteNotification.. when ever this function will be fired, you will get the current date time on [NSDate date]

Comment: You didn't get the requirement. I need the date and time when the push was received by the device (If possible.).

Comment: It is not possible, Except you pass the date in payload, and convert with timezone in which notification arrived.

Comment: Its not possible, to get actual date and time of receiving any Notification. App gets control only if User intentionally tap on that Notification. In that case only app get a delegate call in method `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

Comment: Ok. Got it.
Thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive a callback in the background when the push notification is received.[(source)](http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/)

`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is called when the notification arrives and could be a good place to start your timer.

It seems that there is only 1 catch, if the user force closes your app by swiping it up in the task switcher you won't receive this callback again until they launch your app again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But can't use the method because of the issue you have mentioned.